# Reduce the number of code if possible when creating a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code below creates a folder based on the passed data from my client-side(VueJs) and checks if there's already an existing folder and deletes it if there is otherwise it will create a new one.

My problem here is that I think my code is too long and unreadable although it accomplishes the task that I want to happen.

Can someone help me to make this code better?

```
router.post('/album', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO GALLERY SET ALBUM = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?";
    let body = [req.body.ALBUM, req.body.DESCRIPTION]
    myDB.query(sql, body, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            let directory = `path\\public\\${req.body.ALBUM}`;
            if (fse.existsSync(directory)) {
                fse.removeSync(directory, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success");
                    }
                })
            } else {
                fse.mkdirpSync(directory, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(object);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success");
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Could you add what the `req` object contains in detail? And explain where `fse` is coming from, I'm guessing it's a file system access, but more detail wouldn't hurt.

Comment: What is the benefit from removing the whole directory every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in file system package (fs) provides you with a commands to create directories.

`fs.mkdirSync(path[, options])` [for synchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options)

`fs.mkdir(path[, options], callback)` [for asynchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback)

According to their documentation, you can add an option for recursively creating a folder. It also notes

"*Calling fs.mkdir() when path is a directory that exists results in an error only when recursive is false.*"

With this information, you should be able to force it to always create the folder using only this logic:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.mkdir( directory, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```